# jquery crop image before upload croppie plugin

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, html

Hello I'm facing difficulty in saving the cropped image in CakePHP using **croppie plugin** image is cropped but when saving the image it saves the whole image not the cropped image, after cropping the `src` of crop image it  is correct but  whenever I try to save it, it saves the whole default image.

```js
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
  enableExif: true,
  viewport: {
    width: 180,
    height: 180,
    type: 'circle'
  },
  boundary: {
    width: 190,
    height: 190
  },
  showZoomer: false
});

$('#my_file').on('change', function() {
  $('#tttssss').show();
  $('#user-select-image').hide();

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
      url: e.target.result
    }).then(function() {
      console.log('jQuery bind complete');
    });

  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$('.upload-result').on('click', function(ev) {
  $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      size: 'viewport'
    })


    .then(function(resp) {

      $('#user-select-image').attr('src', resp);
      $('#user-select-image').show();
      $("#tttssss").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user-select-image").click(function() {
    $("input[id='my_file']").click();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="tttssss" style="display:none;">
  <div id="upload-demo">
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;margin: 0 auto;">
    <a class="btn btn-success upload-result" rel="<?php //echo $imge['User']['id'] ?>">Upload Image</a>
  </div>
</div>


<?php echo $this->Html->image($fileuser, array('class' => 'img-circl', 'id' => 'user-select-image', 'style' => 'margin-top:30px!important;')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('User.profile_img', array('id' => 'my_file', 'style' => 'display:none;')); ?>
```

Upload the image it upload the whole image

This is my code

Answer (score 0):

In function:

`$uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      size: 'viewport'
    })`

```
.then(function(resp) {

  $('#user-select-image').attr('src', resp.target.result);
  $('#user-select-image').show();
  $("#tttssss").hide();
});});
```

You must use: `resp.toDataURL()` instead of `resp.target.result`